# Default prop types through a higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

Passing components through a HOC is causing the defaultProps information to be lost to the typescript compiler.  For instance

`themed.tsx`

```
export interface ThemedProps {
    theme: {};
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
export type Subtract<T extends K, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

const themed = <P extends ThemedProps = ThemedProps>(
    ComponentToWrap: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
    return class ThemeWrappedComponent extends React.Component<
         Subtract<P, ThemedProps>
    > {
        static displayName = `themed(${ComponentToWrap.displayName})`;

        theme = () => {
            return {}
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <ComponentToWrap
                    {...this.props as P}
                    theme={this.theme()}
                />
            );
        }
    }
};
```

`Foo.tsx`

```
interface FooProps {
    theme: object,
    name: string,
}

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {
    static defaultProps = {
        name: 'world'
    }
    render() {
        return <span>hello ${this.props.name}</span>
    }
}

export default themed(Foo);
```

When I instantiate `<Foo />`, I get a compiler error saying that `Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<Pick<FooProps, "name">>'.`.

I know there's a way to use `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes` to get around this kind of thing, but I don't know how, and I can't find any documentation on that feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to leverage `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes` to be able to extract required and optional (defaulted) props from wrapped component in your HOC. This looks somewhat tricky:

```
import React from 'react';

interface FooProps {
  theme: string;
  name: string;
}

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {
  static defaultProps = {
    name: 'world',
  };
  render() {
    return <span>hello ${this.props.name}</span>;
  }
}

interface ThemedProps {
  theme: string;
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Subtract<T extends K, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;


const themed = <
  C extends React.ComponentType<React.ComponentProps<C> & ThemedProps>,
  // that's where all the magic happens
  ResolvedProps = JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, Subtract<React.ComponentProps<C>, ThemedProps>>
>(
  Component: C
) => {
  return class ThemeWrappedComponent extends React.Component<ResolvedProps> {
    static displayName = `themed(${ComponentToWrap.displayName})`;

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          // proper typecast since ts has fixed type infering on object rest
          {...this.props as JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, React.ComponentProps<C>>} 
          theme="theme" 
        />
      );
    }
  };
};

const Wrapped = themed(Foo);

const el = <Wrapped />; // works
```

Comment: I think it's important to note, that here `JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, ...>` `C` should be a type, not just a component class, so `typeof ComponentName` will be a correct option for the other case. I spent half an hour trying to figure out why condition `C extends { defaultProps: infer D; }` in @types/react wasn't working for me.